# Simple Jquery Ajax from Mysql advice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this basic HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <form id="search_form" role="form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_search" id="txt_search" placeholder="Enter name here" autocomplete="off" >
    <p></p>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_search" class="btn btn-default">Retrieve </button>
  </div>
  </form>
  <div class="result" id="result">this element used by jquery and replaced by db</div>
</div>
```

I want the user to type in their search query and click the btn_search which will "hopefully" populate (without refreshing the page) the results div (eventually I want to use a graph but for the time being a table is fine).

I have this within my javascript file, specifically this part under the $(document).ready...

```
$('#btn_search').click(function(){
$.ajax({                                      
 url: './php/search.php',        
 data: "",                    
 dataType: 'json',   
 success: function(rows)         
    {
    for (var i in rows)
    {
      var row = rows[i];          
      var id = rows[0];
      var vname = rows[1];
      $('#result').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname).append("<hr />");


     } 
    }
});
});
```

I have checked my search.php page and it returns the values i expect from the database (about 6 columns eventually) so I am wondering why it isn't being correctly displayed on the result div.

I am a beginner trying to pick it all up, no doubt I have much to work on but I am grateful for any advice and for an answer to my problem.

EDIT:  Added search.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["txt_search"])){
    $field_search= $_POST["txt_search"];
}
else{ 
}

//sql
$sql = "SELECT * From tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2  ON tbl1._tbl1.id = tbl2.tbl1_id WHERE tbl1.name like '%$field_search%'";

// Connect to the database
mysql_connect("", "", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die (mysql_error());

// Lets build the query and execute
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$item_num = 0;
$num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

// Put the table data into an array
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
 ?>
```

Comment: When you say that search.php returns the correct values, do you mean that you are typing in the URL manually in your browser and observing the result? Or do you mean that you see the javascript code receiving the result from the PHP script? If you haven't proven to yourself that the JS is getting a proper result, then that is the place to start.

Comment: I don't see anything in your ajax that sends `txt_search` to the php script through ajax.

Comment: what is the actual output and what is wrong whit that? because ` so I am wondering why it isn't being correctly displayed on the result div.` is not much information.

Comment: you aren't preventing the default submit of the form, so page will refresh

Comment: The actual output of the search.php when I call it directly is lots of: ["text19","160","2011-05-30 00:00:00"] as I can see in mysql.  Within the search.php I grab the content of the txt_search before querying the database.

Comment: I've just updated the post with my original php

Comment: You should NOT use THIS search.php at all..... even if it worked. Please don´t use it in production environment. It has an obvious SQL injection security flaw. You should NEVER, NEVER ever use unescaped parameters in a sql-query. Escape your parameter with mysql_escape_string/mysqli_real_escape_string and better use prepared statements.

Comment: Oh yes I am aware of it - I just haven't got that far yet - thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/LsB2d/2/

First, I added `return: false;` to your click function, so the form isn't submitted through html.  Second, I added `txt_search = $('#txt_search').val();` and added `data: txt_search` to your ajax function.  This way, you're actually sending the value of the search input to the PHP file.  If this doesn't work, let us know and we can go from there. (Although not seeing your PHP we can't help you with that yet)

In your PHP, you use `$search = $_GET['search'];`, and now `$search` contains your search string, which can be used to query your db or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, the return false; has certainly improved things.  I'll tidy it up but this looks like it is on the right lines.

Comment: Ok I've got it displaying data but as you expected it doesn't display the content based upon the search.  Once I add data: txt_search to the ajax function how can I use this in the php file?

Comment: We have to see your php.

Comment: Ive added my original search.php - ive taken out the db details hopefully...Ive checked the code and it seems to be repeating the first row - over and over again

Comment: You should be using `$_GET['search']` if you're using the example I gave.  It passes the data as `search`, in the URL as GET.  `$_POST` won't get the right data.

Comment: You can change your data line to `data: {txt_search : txt_search},` in your ajax call, but you still need to use `$_GET['txt_search']` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Yeah I don't know how I missed that one.  I was referring to the 2nd not the 1st part.  Anyway that's helped again.  Now I just need to get it to print out the columns rather than the entire row from the array

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks the content of the result of search.php but I think your mistake is in here - you are iterating over the rows array with the var "i" but are using the rows-variable.... you mixed up iterating over array indices and iterating over array elements

```
for (var i in rows)
{
  var row = rows[i];          
  var id = rows[0];
  var vname = rows[1];
  $('#result').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname).append("<hr />");


 }
```

Think it should be like this

```
for (var row in rows)
{
  var id = row[0];
  var vname = row[1];
  $('#result').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname).append("<hr />");


 }
```

Comment: Thanks - Ive tried this but it mimics the same result as I am already experiencing.  Within the search.php I include: 
if (isset($_POST["txt_search"])){
   $field_search= $_POST["txt_search"];
} before building the database query